# Error When Using Django send_mail() Function

Tags: python, django

I want to send a mail to users that fill the email field in my django app. The process is like this, when a user fill the form, if it's valid, it will save in the database and pick the user email address from the database and send mail. I tried the below codes but I'm getting this error:

```
   ValueError at /confirm/

  need more than 1 value to unpack

   Request Method:  POST
   Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/
   Django Version:  1.4
   Exception Type:  ValueError
   Exception Value:     

   need more than 1 value to unpack

   Exception Location:  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py in sanitize_address, line 102
   Python Executable:   C:\Python27\python.exe
   Python Version:  2.7.3
```

Models

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    email_address=models.EmailField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email_address
```

Views

```
     def invite_me(request):
         if request.method=="POST":
            form=InviteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               #get input data and send email to the user.
               send_mail('Your Key Invite','Welcome to my world','test@gmail.com',
                  [Invite.objects.values('email_address')])
               return HttpResponse('Thanks For Inputting Your Email, Go Check Your Email For Our Invite!')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Email Address')
        else:
            form=InviteForm()
            return render_to_response('home.html',{'InviteForm':InviteForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what `Invite.objects.values('email_address')` returns?  Definitely not what the `send_mail` function accepts (a list of email addresses).

`Invite.objects.values_list('email_address', flat=True)` is what you need. Oh, and remove the `[]`.

`send_mail('foo', 'bar', 'baz@example.com', Invite.objects.values_list(...))`